# MongoDB aggregate with lookup and sort using associated collection fields is slowing down the query

Tags: mongodb, sorting, limit, lookup

I have two collections in my mongodb database as follows:

> ***employee_details*** with approximately 330000 documents which has *department_id* as a reference from departments collection
>
> ***departments*** collections with 2 fields *_id* and *dept_name*

I have added index to the collections as folows

```
db.departments.createIndex( { dept_name: 1 } )
db.employee_details.createIndex( { department_id: 1 } )
db.employee_details.createIndex( { employee_fname: 1 } )
```

I want to fetch the data to list on a data table by joining the two collections. But when I tried to do that I have faced two issues.

First when I add sort after lookup the quer running takes a long time, I have added sort after lookup , since I need to sort with dept_name of collection departments. Query is given below

```
db.getCollection("employee_details").aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      localField: "department_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Department"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: { path: "$Department", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $sort: { "Department.dept_name": 1 } },
  { $limit: 30 }
]);
```

Second when I add the sort above lookup, the query become fast but the result give wrong sorting if I sort using dept_name or department_id( sorting works fine for fields of `employee_details` collection). Query is given below

```
db.getCollection("employee_details").aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: "$Department", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
  { $sort: { "Department.dept_name": 1 } },
  //{ $sort: { "department_id": 1 } }, // tried this also
  { $limit: 30 },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "departments",
      localField: "department_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "Department"
    }
  }
]);
```

Can someone give an optimised solution for fetching the data along with sort from all related collections.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want the output look like _or_ what is the purpose of the resulting dataset?

Comment: I have mentioned in the question. Consider a sample data like cat1, cat2,cat3 in `departments` collection.  There are approximately 3000000 employes who chooses any of the 3 departments.  Then the problem is explained in the question. I cannto add my dataset here , but someone can easly create dataset with my info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following aggregation:

```js
db.getCollection("departments").aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            "dept_name": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "employee_details",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "department_id",
            as: "employees"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$employees"
    },
    {
        $limit: 30
    },
    { $addFields: { "employees.department_name": "$dept_name" } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$employees" } }
])
```

This will work for MongoDB version 3.4, it will be fast enough even without any indexes.

Comment: @Ajith  can you please try this solution and give feedback whether it is working correctly and fast.

Comment: @Sah Thanks a lot, This seems to be an elegant solution

Comment: @Ajith I am happy that al last we resolved your problem. Please don't forget to upvote and mark this as answer.

Comment: @Sah One more question, I have add  skip within your existing query and I find the following observations  If skip is 330000  It takes 8 Sec Then skip = 250000  then 5 sec . skip = 150000  then 4.5 sec .  skip = 50000  then 1 sec .  This is just a comment, I am curious to know why this happens . I am happy with the worse case 9 sec .. Thanks a alot brother

Comment: @Ajith it seems when the skip increases, respose time also increases. I guess this is related with inner working of mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.departments.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "dept_name": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "employee_details",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "department_id",
      as: "Employee"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$Employee"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            Department: "$$ROOT"
          },
          "$Employee"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "tmp.Department.Employee": 0
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "tmp.Department": [
        "$tmp.Department"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 30
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/COpDQtSyQXF)

Comment: This seems to be an optiomised solution. But you need to do `$unwind` and `$project` after `$lookup`

Comment: @Ajith yes. Please provide sample data

Comment: Data is huge, I cant share here for some reason. I just note about `$unwind` and `$project` ,  thanks for your answer.   Also expecting more answers

Comment: Got Error as Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unset'

Comment: @Ajith check again please. I've improvised sample data

Comment: Still got error as : "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$mergeObjects'"

Comment: @Ajith You have old version MongoDB, so we cannot use "generic" solution. So you need to transform expected result manually by `$project` (after `$unwind: "$Employee"`) you need to do it manually

Comment: Which mongo version you recommend

Comment: @Ajith $mergeObjects came with Mongodb version 3.6? So your version seems older than 3.6

Comment: Ohh yes, My mongoDB version is 3.4

Comment: @Ajith does the playground result is what you want? becase using limit after sort will only limit the departments. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ub8gaoFCxmq) I limited 5, but in the result all of the documents appear, this seems to be not working.

Comment: @SuleymanSah No, we need first sort + limit to use `indexes`. The last `$limit` executed in pipeline and doesn't affect to performance (if we sort at the last step, MongoDB will order in memory with top-k algorithm which has bad performance)

Comment: @SuleymanSah why you delete your answer, let me check If it solve my issue

Comment: @Ajith I noticed a problem, I will post in half an hour

Comment: @SuleymanSah okay thanks :)  It will be good if you explain in details of each steps inside aggregation